# Making a python 2 Tkinter slider static under certain conditions

Tags: python, slider, tkinter

I was wondering if there was a way to make a slider static under certain conditions, i.e. the program is under trial license.

One solution I've thought up was putting an image instead of a slider, but I'd prefer a static slider.

Is there a way I could do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `state=DISABLED` option in the constructor, which is allowed in almost all Tkinter widgets.

Comment: how about when I also need it to have a default value?

Comment: In that case you can create a IntVar, set the default value, and pass it as the `variable` option. It also works when the state of the widget is `NORMAL`.